# I have a simple website which images load on my computer but not on server

Tags: html, css, image, png, server

This website consists of a few html pages, css, and 4 PNG images. I'm very new to server side as I'm more of a web designer, and I can't seem to figure out why the images load when I open up the local files, but not online from the hosting I'm using. Currently I'm just using Byethost to get my feet wet before I purchase anything, and everything else on the website (html and css) load fine without problem. I'm putting the files in the designated spot using the online file manager from the Cpanel. I've tried putting the images in a separate file and linking to them accordingly with my html, and I'm not using absolute path like `src="c/name/documents/Project file/photo.png"`, I'm using relative path like `src="img/photo.png"` or simply `src="photo.png"`.

What should I be looking at for the problem, the hosting? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

EDIT: I get "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" in the console.

Comment: First of all, that's not what "absolute path" and "relative path" means. Secondly, what is the images' path *supposed* to be? In what directory are they in the server? Can you access them directly (by typing in their address in the URL bar)?

Comment: ... Yeah it is? I'm linking inside my working directory instead of the absolute path like on my local computer.

Comment: Absolute path means something like `http://example.com/path/to/file.txt` or `/path/to/file.txt`, that is, the URI can be accessed from anywhere in the directory tree. Relative path means *relative to the current directory* like `../file.txt` or `path/to/file.txt`. What you're talking about are *local paths* versus *HTML paths*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the extension of your images if they are .PNG or .png.
Some servers are straight with that